# std::div - неоднозначность вызова с аргументом std::size_t

Tags: c++

Хотел выполнить деление с одновременным получением частного и остатка следующим образом:

```
auto result = std::div (a, b); // тип a и b - std::size_t
```

Но в c++ нет версии std::div для аргументов типа std::size_t, а этот тип мне необходим для пущей переносимости. Возникает неоднозначность при вызове std::div, т.к. c++ не знает к какому типу преобразовать std::size_t - int, long или long long.

Может, кто-нибудь подскажет, как пооптимальнее выполнить деление, поборов неоднозначность и не теряя переносимости?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из исходника GNU libc:

```
/* Return the `div_t' representation of NUMER over DENOM.  */
div_t
div (numer, denom)
     int numer, denom;
{
  div_t result;

  result.quot = numer / denom;
  result.rem = numer % denom;

  return result;
}
```

Так что не парьтесь. Т.к. у вас беззнаковые переменные, можете упростить:

```
result.quot = numer / denom;
result.rem = numer - denom * result.quot;
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы правы. Правда вы взяли исходник из C-шной библиотеки, но оказалось и в C++ - то же самое.

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант. Если есть поддержка C++14 в компиляторе, то пишем простую обёртку:

```
template<typename T>
auto Div(T a, T b)
{
    using Signed_t = typename std::make_signed<T>::type;
    auto max = static_cast<T>(std::numeric_limits<Signed_t>::max);
    assert(a <= max && b <= max);
    return std::div(static_cast<Signed_t>(a), static_cast<Signed_t>(b));
}
```

Если есть поддержка только C++11, то обёртка будет немного страшнее:

```
template<typename T>
auto Div(T a, T b) -> decltype(std::div(static_cast<typename std::make_signed<T>::type>(a), 
    static_cast<typename std::make_signed<T>::type>(b)))
{
    using Signed_t = typename std::make_signed<T>::type;
    auto max = static_cast<T>(std::numeric_limits<Signed_t>::max);
    assert(a <= max && b <= max);
    return std::div(static_cast<Signed_t>(a), static_cast<Signed_t>(b));
}
```

Данный вариант поддерживает все 3 типа, которые может возвратить `std::div` и принимает все аргументы, который принимает `std::div`, включая их беззнаковые пары.

---

А вообще говоря, самое простое и правильное решение использовать `ptrdiff_t` вместо `size_t`. `ptrdiff_t` это знаковый аналог `size_t`. С `ptrdiff_t` можно использовать `std::div` без проблем.

Comment: Эхм. Каст в signed может обрезать значение.

Comment: @VladD, конечно может. Но раз автор пытался запихнуть `size_t` в `std::div` это должно его устраивать.

Comment: С другой стороны, а вдруг у ТС квалификация ниже вашей? И он не подумал. :)

Comment: @VladD, я всегда думаю о людях в положительном ключе :) Тем не менее, добавил проверку и альтернативное решение вопроса.

Comment: Просто я думал, что div как-то оптимально построен, а раз он все равно выполняет / и %, то он мне и не нужен. А вот size_t мне как раз нужен :)